# How To Remove Padding of Iframe from page

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to remove padding (few pixel) of iframe. when we use iframe in any page and make its height & width 100% but it left few pixels from all side left, right, up & down.how to remove it. Please look at this URL.
http://mindmaker.org.in/frame.php
i have remove scroll bar from this page but few pixels are not remove from all side

Answer (score 6):

You have to reset default `<body>` padding / margin.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

add frameBorder="0" (capital "B")

```
<iframe src="http://pragswebsolution.in/onlinetest/orgnisation.php" height="100%"         width="100%" frameBorder="0" style="overflow-y: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Comment: well its not working but my problem is already solved with first reply. But also thx for taking interest in my queation